# How to create and send an email to multiple clients

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I work in an insurance company and for different clients I have to send emails about promotions and greetings, etc. How to create an email in Outlook with images and cards and then send it to about 50 to 70 clients?

Answer (score 2):

In your address book you can make both individual and group entries.

Comment: Are you able to explain HOW you do this?

Comment: So I couldn't even assume he knows how to add contacts in his own email client? How silly do you want to look, Mr Postill? Anyways, here's a link to explain: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/outlook/manage-people-contact-list All you need to know in addition to what you find here is that you can choose groups as recipients.

Comment: Preferably in blind carbon copy field I might add unless you absolutely must show all the recipients who got the email. BCC is a must if you want something to look personal.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Outlook and click on the Contacts icon
2. Click New Contact Group button in  the Home tab.
3. click Add Members and add members from  address book
4. enter the name of group
5. click save
6. send a mail by adding group name in "TO" field .
7. one can check who's in the distribution list by clicking the plus (+) sign besides the Contact Group name and you can make modifications as per
8. click on send to send email to a group